# How to automatically change default version to the latest one on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

As far as I know, you need to manually change the default version on app engine admin panel after you deployed a new version. Is there a way to automatically change default version to the latest one?

Answer (score 1):

You can `appcfg.py [options] set_default_version` as documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp -- i.e, use a two-line shell script or cmd file, doing the `set_default_version` right after the `update`.  **However**, this won't work right if you've changed `index.yaml` since the index needs to be rebuilt, which takes time; in this case you must not `set_default_version` until the new index is ready (again, that `uploadinganapp` URL explains this well).